# arraylist undefined method for type

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

I have a method which takes an `ArrayList<Song>` as argument.
the class song has different methods like getTitle(), getInterpret(), toString(), toString2()...

```
public class Song implements Comparable<Song>{

    private String title;
    private String interpret;
    
    public Song(String title,String interpret){
        
        this.title=title;
        this.interpret=interpret;
        
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getInterpret() {
        return interpret;
    }

    
    public String toString2(){
        return title+" - "+interpret;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Song otherSong) {
        
        return title.compareToIgnoreCase(otherSong.getTitle());
    }

    public String toString() {
        
        return interpret+" - "+title;
    }

}
```

the method printList takes an ArrayList of Song as argument:

```
public <Song> void printList(ArrayList<Song> songList,String sortBy){
    
    JLabel track;
            
    for(int i=0;i<songList.size();i++){

        if(sortBy=="Artist"){
        track = new JLabel("\n- "+songList.get(i).toString());}

        else if(sortBy=="Song"){
        track = new JLabel("\n- "+songList.get(i).toString2());}
        
    }
```

I have an error on songList.get(i).toString2(), the method toString2() is undefined for type Song, it seems like I can only access to the method of the class Object.

Can somebody help please?

Comment: why do you name method `toString2()` ?

Comment: hi, because toString2() is just a variation of toString()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've made your method generic, and chose to name the generic type Song. It shouldn't be generic:

```
public void printList(ArrayList<Song> songList,String sortBy){
```

Also, compare strings with `equals()`, not `==`.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but when i remove the "<Song>" in the method declaration, the compiler tells me "Song cannot be resolved to a type", do you know why?